# want video and library both in gallery in android

Tags: android, android-intent

When picking a `file` from the Library,  only photos are listed. Video files should also be shown.

Im Using this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Answer (score 0):

use following for pick both images and videos.

```
Intent mediaChooser =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
//comma-separated MIME types
mediaChooser.setType("video/*, images/*");
startActivityForResult(mediaChooser,IMAGE_PICK);
```